# Use of updategram to describe a 'not' condition in before filter

Tags: db2, biztalk

In use of update gram to update a table in DB2, the previous developer used update gram but the filter was not done right, requirement is if do the update if certain column 'is not' of some value.

Not really used much of updategram, I know how to do the filter if the column 'is' of some value, but how to achiever this 'is not' condition?

Comment: What have you tried so far? What were the outcomes?  Possibly you would be better of posting this in the database forum

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BizTalk provides a logical functoid for Not Equal, the icon for which is `<>` on a turquoise background.

Comment: They are not talking about maps here, so your answer is not relevant.